# angular watch causing looping Iligal invocation error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a [modal dialog](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) where the user can select files to be uploaded. The actual file select/upload is handled by [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload). When the user selects one or more file, they are added to a list in the dialog, showing progress, completion and failure statuses for each element. The list of items are handled inside a custom directive, since it's used other places as well.

I need to prevent the user from dismissing the dialog while files are still uploading, and that's a challenge for me, cause the button for closing the dialog is in one controller, while the list of uploads is in another (the directive controller). I have solved that by giving and empty list to the directive like this:

```
//extract from directive:
var directive = {
      ...
      scope: {
        'files': '='
      }
   }

//extract from usage
<uploadFiles files="files" />
```

Now the outer controller and the inner controller shares the list of files uploading.

So when the user tries to dismiss the dialog by clicking the `Close` button, I first check if the list contains files still uploading, and if so, I disable the button and display a spinner and a 'please wait'-text.

```
//from the outer controller
function onModalOk() {
    if (uploadInProgress()) {
        waitForCompletionBeforeClosingDialog();
    } else {
        closeDialog();
    }
}
```

the `waitForCompletionBeforeClosingDialog()` is implemented by setting up a deep watch on the files array. Each time the watch is triggered, I loop through to see if every file has completed. If so, I delete the watch and dismiss the dialog.

```
    function waitForCompletionBeforeClosingDialog() {
        $scope.showWaitText = true;
        var unregisterWatchForCompletion = $scope.$watch('files',  function(files) {
            if (allCompleted(files)) {
                unregisterWatchForCompletion();
                closeDialog();
            } 
        }, true);
    }
```

Everything is working ok, except for one little thing...

In the console, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at equals (angular.js:931)
    at equals (angular.js:916)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14302)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
    at angular.js:16308
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:4924)
    at angular.js:5312
```

and it's fired in a tight loop.

I have tried debugging this error, but with no luck..
Do anyone have any ideas?
Is there better ways of doing this all together?

Answer (score 0):

What about using an `$httpInterceptor` to keep count of the amount of active requests?

something like:

```
angular.module('someModule').provider('httpStatus', ['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {


    var currentRequestCount = 0;
    var interceptor = ['$q', function ($q) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                currentRequestCount++;

                return config;
            },
            response: function (response) {
                currentRequestCount--;

                return response;
            },
            responseError: function (rejection) {
                currentRequestCount--;

                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    }];

   $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
   this.$get = function () {
        return {
            isWaiting: function () {
                return currentRequestLength > 0;
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

You could inject the `httpStatus` service into your dialog and use it to disable the buttons if there are any active requests. May need to add the `requestError` handler also.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: How easy will it be to keep track of only fileuploads and not every other request that might be going on?

Comment: You could inspect the request objects and only count the ones that you care about. Check for `multipart/form-data` for instance.

Comment: I ended up using event for this instead. Emitting events whenever a upload starts or ends. When the user clicks the ok button, an event is sent to the directive, which again sends an event back with status information.